# How to query a table using filter with a condition in Flask Sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am having bunch of records with column 'date_time' (eg: `2021-08-01 09:45`). I am trying to query records using a filter by present month, but I am getting 'AttributeError'. Help me here.

```
    today = date.today()    
    records = SomeTable.query.filter(
                  SomeTable.date_time.date().month == date.month).all()
```

Error Message:

```
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with SomeTable.date_time has an attribute 'date'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using extract method from sqlalchemy package does the job

```
from sqlalchemy import extract

today = data.today()
records = SomeTable.query.filter(
             extract('month', SomeTable.date_time) == today.month).all()
```